# Float Label Pattern for Select Boxes

Tags: forms, interaction-design, input-fields, help

I'm sure you've all come across this pattern, does anyone know whether there is any documentation that can provide information on how this pattern can be used with other form elements for example a select-box and not just text input elements?

Further information about this pattern:
http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/float-label-pattern/

[image]

Comment: It's a bit gimmicky. Call me old-fashioned by why not design the form so that there is enough room for the full-size label to sit about the fields at all time instead?

Comment: i understand where your coming from and maybe the old fashioned way might be best but taking into consideration this pattern i was interested in finding out more about how it can be applied to other form elements.

Comment: Personally I really like it, from a UX standpoint. Large, obvious prompts for input then keeping the title in place once an entry is type, unlike traditional watermarks, the users knows what the form field is for.

Comment: this only works if hint and label have the same text. under some circumstances this might not be the case.

Comment: @DarrylGodden: The trouble is that it already looks like the fields have been filled in before anything has been written. That's one of the problems with placeholder text, so the same issue is present here with these weird floating labels.

Comment: @JonW I disagree, unless you test I would hazard a guess that people would not be confused as to believe they'd entered generic values such as "First Name" etc... could be wrong, but with limited space it's a viable solution.

Comment: @DarrylGodden: The issue isn't that they think they've entered 'First Name' in the field, but that *at a glance it looks filled in* so they skip over the field without reading the content. I haven't tested it myself, but I know people who have - such as [Caroline Jarrett](http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2010/03/dont-put-hints-inside-text-boxes-in-web-forms.php) - author of the fantastic 'Forms that Work', and probably someone who knows more about forms than most people on the planet.

Comment: We're implementing methods here, not dictum's, there will always be cases where the best method you choose will still confuse and obfuscate people, no matter how much effort you put into it. So with that said, I reiterate, I like it. It suits modern mobile forms to a tee.

Comment: @JonW - just to add, it's a interesting article. The comments are interesting too, which proves the point that you can have all the expertise in the world, it doesn't mean everyone is going to take your advise at face value, and why should they?

Comment: The benefit of this pattern seems to be that there is no tracking required between field and label (and a more compact UI), since they are combined. And then once the user has entered some text we see a subtle label being created. The label could be there to entire time, it is just removed whilst not required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have modified the [Float Pattern Demo](http://codepen.io/aaronbarker/pen/tIprm) to work on a select box.

First things first, I added a **State** wrapper, label, and box to the HTML form with all the states in there as options.  I included a default item with the text `State` and an empty string for its value.  This way I could easily tell if it was selected vs an actual state option.

Next, I modified the CSS by putting in 2 styles. `option { color: black; }` and `.watermark { color: #aaa }`.  The first one defaults the select options to black.  The second one is used to change the option color to a gray, just like the watermarks on the other input elements, based on the default item being selected or not.

The last thing I had to do was modify the jQuery to hook up the select box.  So the way this originally worked was that it bound a function called `checkval` that would toggle the visibility of the floating label and attached listeners to the `keyup`, `focus`, and `blur` events for all `input` elements.

I needed a way to hook in the `select`, so what I did was modify the selector to include `select`, so it becomes `$("input, select")`.  The next thing I had to do was attach a specific listener for the select `change` event, as that's the one that gets fired when a selection has been made.  Then all I had to do was write some code that would toggle off and on the watermark class I made earlier based on whether or not the currently selected item's value had a value or not.  After that, it simply makes a call to the `checkval` function to toggle visibility on the select box's floating label.

I haven't tested it in all browsers, but seems to me that it's identical to the other floating labels and keeps the user experience consistent and clean.

Enjoy!

### [See working CopePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GHKJj)

---

### HTML

```
<div class="field-wrapper">
  <label for="fname">First Name</label>
  <input name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
</div>

<div class="field-wrapper">
  <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
  <input name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
</div>

<div class="field-wrapper">
  <label for="city">City</label>
  <input name="city" placeholder="City" />
</div>

<div class="field-wrapper">
  <label for="state">State</label>
  <select name="State" placeholder="State"> 
    <option value="" selected="selected">State</option> 
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option> 
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option> 
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option> 
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option> 
    <option value="CA">California</option> 
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option> 
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option> 
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option> 
    <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option> 
    <option value="FL">Florida</option> 
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option> 
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option> 
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option> 
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option> 
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option> 
    <option value="IA">Iowa</option> 
    <option value="KS">Kansas</option> 
    <option value="KY">Kentucky</option> 
    <option value="LA">Louisiana</option> 
    <option value="ME">Maine</option> 
    <option value="MD">Maryland</option> 
    <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option> 
    <option value="MI">Michigan</option> 
    <option value="MN">Minnesota</option> 
    <option value="MS">Mississippi</option> 
    <option value="MO">Missouri</option> 
    <option value="MT">Montana</option> 
    <option value="NE">Nebraska</option> 
    <option value="NV">Nevada</option> 
    <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option> 
    <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option> 
    <option value="NM">New Mexico</option> 
    <option value="NY">New York</option> 
    <option value="NC">North Carolina</option> 
    <option value="ND">North Dakota</option> 
    <option value="OH">Ohio</option> 
    <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option> 
    <option value="OR">Oregon</option> 
    <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option> 
    <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option> 
    <option value="SC">South Carolina</option> 
    <option value="SD">South Dakota</option> 
    <option value="TN">Tennessee</option> 
    <option value="TX">Texas</option> 
    <option value="UT">Utah</option> 
    <option value="VT">Vermont</option> 
    <option value="VA">Virginia</option> 
    <option value="WA">Washington</option> 
    <option value="WV">West Virginia</option> 
    <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option> 
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

---

### CSS

```
.field-wrapper 
{
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
label 
{
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #aaa;
  transition: all 0.1s linear;
  opacity: 0;
  font-weight:b old;
}
label.on 
{
  color: #4481C4;
}
label.show 
{
  top: -15px;
  opacity: 1;
}
option
{
  color: black;
}
.watermark
{
  color: #aaa;
}
body 
{
  padding: 20px;
    /* the following line fixes a blink in chrome https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108025 */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

---

### JQUERY

```
$(function () 
{
  var onClass = "on";
  var showClass = "show";

  $("input, select")
    .bind("checkval", function () 
    {
      var label = $(this).prev("label");
        
      if (this.value !== "")
        label.addClass(showClass);
        
      else
        label.removeClass(showClass);
    })
    .on("keyup", function () 
    {
      $(this).trigger("checkval");
    })
    .on("focus", function () 
    {
      $(this).prev("label").addClass(onClass);
    })
    .on("blur", function () 
    {
        $(this).prev("label").removeClass(onClass);
    })
    .trigger("checkval");
    
  $("select")
    .on("change", function ()
    {
      var $this = $(this);
      
      if ($this.val() == "")
        $this.addClass("watermark");
      
      else
        $this.removeClass("watermark");
        
      $this.trigger("checkval");
    })
    .change();
});
```

Comment: This is *how* to do it in code but doesn't discuss any of the user experience benefits / negatives of the approach, nor does it cover off how such an approach works with select boxes (the main aspect of this question).

Comment: @JonW - This is a direct answer to his question of how to make the pattern work with elements other than inputs, such as selects.  If you view the demo, it's very easy to see the user experience, as a user yourself.  That's why I linked it.  I definitely can put in a description of what I did though for sure.

Comment: @JonW - Description has been added =D

Answer (score 2):

The "floating" is not the important part of the style - what you have here are two style elements:

1. Field title only shows after field is filled
2. Blue highlight for current field

I'm not sure how much this style actually makes the form better, but for a multiple choice field you would do the same - drop-down which has the title until an option is picked, and a small title above it which highlights in blue when the drop-down is open.

Answer (score 0):

For active input elements you can have a "halo burst" appear when the select box gets focus, or, in the case of check-boxes, gets activated, etc.

Comment: "Halo Burst?" - could you provide some examples please

Comment: @KyleMcBride - Most modern browsers do that on their own.  Take a look in Safari, Firefox, or Chrome.  If you want to handle it yourself, use [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).